# Install Odoo V8 on ubuntu?

Tags: odoo, openerp-8

What is the step-by-step process to install Odoo on Ubuntu platform?

Also, what is major difference between OpenERP and Odoo?

Comment: Ubuntu and Debian should install well with this: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-set-up-openerp-7-0-on-a-debian-7-ubuntu-13-10-vps or https://www.odoo.com/forum/Help-1/question/openerp-7-debian-7-wheezy-28968

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no major difference between OpenERP and Odoo excluding

- The version - 7 to 8
- Rebranded name - OpenERP to Odoo
- New features - from ERP to Business Suite

Thanks
Kadri

Answer (score 0):

ODOO is the new name of the openERP

In the older version openERP doen't  feet for the Website Builder and Blog, e-commerce and much and more therefore the openERP name  doen't feet for the business.
so, the ODOO is the new concept,new ideas and new innovation in openERP 8.

Installation of ODOO in ubuntu from the git reefer the below link

http://pulse7.net/openerp/install-odoo-open-erp-v8-ubuntu-12-04-launchpad/

This should help you